# View Notifications from Linkedin Api

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, linkedin-api

I am integrating linkedin api in my rails app..I have implemented every functionalities except view notifications.

Can any one please give me any way or link to implement.

Thanks in advance

Aurick